# Align titles in center of page

Tags: angular, sass

In my Angular project, I want to write first `title1` then a second `title2` and next to it there is 2 images as the following image:

[image]

HTML :

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <p class="Title1">title1<p>
            <div class="imageContainer">
                <p class="Title2">title2</p>
                <img class="image2" src="assets/c.png" alt="Your Image">
                <img class="image" src="assets/Loader.gif" alt="Your Image">
            </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <p class="Title1">title1<p>
            <div class="imageContainer">
                <p class="Title2">title2</p>
                <img class="image2" src="assets/c.png" alt="Your Image">
                <img class="image" src="assets/Loader.gif" alt="Your Image">
            </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 60px; 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }

.Title1{
    font-family: Lufga;
    color: black;
    font-size: 5 em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
   text-align: center;

}

.image{
  max-width: 25%;
  display: block; 
  margin-left: 10px; 
  margin-top: 0%;
  // margin-bottom: 10%; 
  // margin-left: 5%;
  
}
.image2{
    max-width: 2.5%;
    display: block; 
    //margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 23%; 
       
  }

.imageContainer {
   // margin-bottom: 70%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 24%;
  }
  
  .Title2 {
    font-family: Lufga;
    color: black;
    font-size: 23 em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

The problem is font size of two titles are the same but normally `title2` should be bigger and also I have a space between the first row and the second one besides the second image is not on center so I used the margin to make it in center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes here:

1. You have given display `flex` with `flex-direction: column` to `.container`, but it has only one child `.col-md-6`, here either remove `.col-md-6` or give display `flex` to this.
2. For `font-size`, you have given `5 em`, remove space here, use like `5em`
3. close you `<p>` tag correctly with `</p>`
4. To keep content on same row, in display `flex` remove `flex-direction: column;`, default `flex-direction` is `row`, so you don't need to add this.

Here is the example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 60px;
/*   flex-direction: column;
   */  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.Title1 {
  font-family: Lufga;
  color: black;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;

}

.image {
  max-width: 25%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0%;
/*   // margin-bottom: 10%; 
  // margin-left: 5%;
   */
}

.image2 {
  max-width: 2.5%;
  display: block;
 /*  //margin-left: 10px;  */
  margin-bottom: 23%;

}

.imageContainer {
/*   // margin-bottom: 70%;
   */  margin-top: 0%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 24%;
}

.Title2 {
  font-family: Lufga;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="Title1">title1</p>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <p class="Title2">title2</p>
    <img class="image2" src="assets/c.png" alt="Your Image">
    <img class="image" src="assets/Loader.gif" alt="Your Image">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="Title1">title1</p>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <p class="Title2">title2</p>
    <img class="image2" src="assets/c.png" alt="Your Image">
    <img class="image" src="assets/Loader.gif" alt="Your Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

change `font-size` and spacings as per your need.

Comment: it works thanks but i get a problem it's not responsive how to correct it

Comment: @ingmbk for responsive, you can use css media queries, read more about them at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)

Comment: When the answer helps you solve the issue, consider upvote and mark as accepted answer to show your appreciation :)

Comment: oky i have another question using % for font doesn't make it responsive ? i mean is there difference on mobile screen and pc screen ?

Comment: no, `%` in `font-size` is for base font size (read as `%` of base font size), not for responsive (the size of viewport has nothing to do here). for responsive css using media query, check the link in previous comment.